# Green bar at right side in full screen VLC

Tags: 14.10, vlc

As seen in the picture I have a colored bar on the right side of my screen when I watch sth in VLC fullscreen. This happens on my pirmary display and also on a projector. It also accurs when the projector is unplugged.

Sometimes it is green, but also purple or a mix of colors.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Go to Tools->Preferences->Video, set Output to "X11 video output (XCB)" and see if it's better.

Comment: Did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (green bar on the right) in addition to a purple bar on the left side of my screen.

## Solution #1

Under System Settings > Displays, on the left, try changing your Resolution/Aspect Ratio until it looks right. For me switching from a 16:9 ratio to a 16:10 worked but I wasn't into the lower resolution so I explored a little more and found another solution.

## Solution #2

I'm not sure what kind of monitor setup you have, but as you can see I have a 27" monitor alongside a 23". The "Scale window contents to match" option defaults to the biggest controls found, and changing it to the smaller controls (for me the 23" controls) also fixed the issue without me having to change the resolution.

[image]

Hope this helps